# Spring boot Data too long for column

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i am creating the userregistation using springboot mysql.i couldn't make a new registation before set the hash password it is working fine after set the password not working what tried so far i attached below.i have attached full error below. i tried many ways but couldn't.

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'password' at row 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3375) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3908) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3303) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2438) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
```

EmployeeImpl.java

```
@Service
public class EmployeeIMPL implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepo employeeRepo;

    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Override
    public String addEmployee(EmployeeDTO employeeDTO) {


        this.passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        Employee employee = new Employee(

                employeeDTO.getEmployeeid(),
                employeeDTO.getEmployeename(),
                employeeDTO.getEmail(),

                this.passwordEncoder.encode(employeeDTO.getPassword())
        );

        employeeRepo.save(employee);

        return employee.getEmployeename();
    }
}
```

**Employee**

```
@Id
    @Column(name="employee_id", length = 45)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int employeeid;

    @Column(name="employee_name", length = 255)
    private String employeename;

    @Column(name="email", length = 255)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password", length = 20)
    private String password;
```

Comment: apparently the hash length is greater than the length of your password column

Comment: so how to solve this problemmm

Comment: change the length of password column to length of your hash. You can change it in your annotaion in domain @Column(name="password", length = <length of hash here>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of hash of your password is greater than the `password` column in your DB.

From your domain:

```
@Column(name="password", length = 20)
private String password;
```

So, increase the length of your column with parameter `length` in your annotation.

Also, it is better to re-create the database.